# Event disconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to learn nodejs with this french tutorial for a chat with nodejs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jkkd2Ohte8

But I can't get the user who leave the room.

Server.js

```
var http = require('http');

httpServer = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    // some magic
});

httpServer.listen(1337);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);
var users = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

    var user = false;

    for(var k in users){
        socket.emit('newUser', users[k]);
    }

    socket.on('login', function(user){
        user = user;
        users[user.id] = user;
        io.sockets.emit('newUser', user);
    });

    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('LOGOUT');
        console.log(user);
        if(!user){
            return false;
        }
        delete users[user.id];
        io.sockets.emit('logout', user)
    });
});
```

And my client.js

```
(function($){

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');
    var rand   =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);

    socket.emit('login', {
        id : rand,
        username : 'Guest' + rand
    })

    socket.on('newUser', function(user){
        $('#users').append('<li id="u'+ user.id +'"><a href="http://rencontre-ados.net/profil'+ user.id +'">'+ user.username + '</a></li>');
    });

    socket.on('logout', function(user){
        $('#users #u'+ user.id).remove();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

When I disconnect from the chat LOGOUT appear in my console but user is **false** so i can't remove the id from my list of connected users.

Comment: tried emit the logout before the delete ?

Comment: @Pogrindis : Same result

Comment: move var user = false; outsive of the scope so that on each connection its not setting it back to false ?

Comment: Same result again user is false :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to save user in users by socket.id since you have access to socket.id in the disconnect event:

```
socket.on('login', function(user){
    users[socket.id] = user;  // <<<<< use socket.id
    io.sockets.emit('newUser', user);
});
socket.on('disconnect', function(){ 
    var user = users[socket.id];  // <<<< use socket.id
    console.log('LOGOUT');
    console.log(user);
    io.sockets.emit('logout', user)
    delete users[socket.id];
});
```

Comment: It's work.Not sure to understand all, but I'll check some documentation. Thank you

Comment: every connection has a unique id (socket.id) generated by socket.io, so you're very safe to use socket.id as key for your users object

Comment: btw, for newUser event, replace your current for loop with this: Object.keys(users).forEach(function(key) {
   socket.emit('newUser', users[key]);
});

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
user = user;
```

To

```
this.user = user;
```

You are reassigning the variable `user` within the same scope. Your goal is to manipulate the parent scope.